# How to configure Chromium-based Brave browser to persist DevTools script ignore list

Tags: brave-browser

DevTools allow scripts to be blackboxed/ignored so they will never open in the debugger even when you choose to step into one of its functions.

Brave v1.34.80, however, appears to be clearing these settings each time I launch. How can they be persisted?

Before closing Brave, I will add an item here:
[image: Settings]

And after restarting Brave, it is gone:
[image]